# Rails Spree App Routing Error: 'uninitialized constant'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree

I am new to Spree, starting with a basic app, I added new controller and view to display a custom static page (templater). It was working a week ago then when I came back to it, it suddenly stopped working. Not sure if I missed something.

The error presented is:

```
Routing Error
uninitialized constant TemplaterController

Rails.root: /Users/MDB/Dropbox/party/Github/basic_spree_store
```

Here is my `app/controllers/spree/templater_controller.rb`:

```
module Spree
    class TemplaterController < Spree::StoreController

    def index

    end
  end
end
```

My `routes.rb`:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  mount Spree::Core::Engine, :at => '/'

  get '/templater', :to => 'templater#index', :as => :templater
end
```

Any tips on how I can troubleshoot something like this would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**spree** is built by rails and rails has some paradigm, one of the paradigm is convention over configuration, one of the convention : controller is plural dan model is singular.

in controller

> templates_controller.rb

```
module Spree
    class TemplatesrController < Spree::StoreController

   def index

   end

end

Rails.application.routes.draw do
  mount Spree::Core::Engine, :at => '/'
  resources :templaters 
end
```

resources know as multiple routes, it will generate routes for some actions which  is index, show, new, edit, create, update and destroy

from your requirement you want to use single resource without follow convention, so please 
avoid to use action name or method index, show, new, edit, create, update and destroy.
Let say we use list

> template_controller.rb

```
module Spree
  class TemplaterController < Spree::StoreController 
    def list

    end
  end
end
```

> routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  mount Spree::Core::Engine, :at => '/'

  get '/templater', :to => 'templater#list', :as => :templater
end
```

You can learn more detail from [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Answer (score 0):

Since yr inheriting `Spree::StoreController` in yr controller, you need to change yr routes.rb a bit, like so:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  mount Spree::Core::Engine, :at => '/'
end

Spree::Core::Engine.add_routes do
  get 'templater', :to => 'templater#index', :as => :templater
end
```

then just make sure you've an `app/view/spree/templater/index.html.erb` file and then you can use `templater_path` to `link_to` that view.